# scalac -explaintypes: What does "<notype> <: X?" mean?

Tags: scala

If I run "scalac -explaintypes" and see something like:

```
Nothing <: ThingManager?
  <notype> <: ThingManager?
  false
true
```

What does the line "<notype > <: ThingManager?" mean?

Does it mean "No type could possibly conform to ThingManager" ?

Comment: It would help to include a small snippet of code that triggers this output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-explain-types` traces all calls to subtyping checks. Indentation is used to show recursive calls.

Here's a small example:

```
scala210 -explaintypes -e '0 : java.lang.String'
scalacmd9062993631372828655.scala:1: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: java.lang.String
0 : java.lang.String
^
one error found
Int(0) <: java.lang.String?
  Int <: java.lang.String?
    <notype> <: java.lang.String?
    false
  false
false
```

There are three levels of recursion. The first call is checking if `UniqueConstantType(0) <:< UniqueTypeRef(String)`. The LHS is is a singleton type for the literal integer. The check continues by [considering](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/22c15143a58af442de08b35fd3bb5ff0f44d6990/src/compiler/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L4853) the underlying type of that singleton type `UniqueTypeRef(Int) <:< UniqueTypeRef(String)`.

The conformance check then [searches](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/22c15143a58af442de08b35fd3bb5ff0f44d6990/src/compiler/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L4702) for the a supertype of `Int` of the class `String` (the [base type](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/22c15143a58af442de08b35fd3bb5ff0f44d6990/src/compiler/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L543)), and then checking if this conforms to `String`. There is no such supertype, so `NoType` is returned. The recursive call to `<:<` leads to the output `<notype> <: java.lang.String`.

```
sym2.isClass && {
  val base = tr1 baseType sym2  // UniqueTypeRef(Int) baseType String => NoType
  (base ne tr1) && base <:< tr2
}
```

`NoType` is a Null Object. (The compiler also uses this pattern for `NoSymbol`, `NoPosition`).